# Web Push Is Not Being Executed In Job Scheduler

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, jobs, apscheduler

The job scheduler is being executed but for some reason the web push is not activated.I tried calling the web push function without the job scheduler and it does trigger a notification on browser. However, nothing gets triggered when I call it in the add_job scheduler function. The GET reminders should be called after the job scheduler if the web push were to be activated FYI. Please help.

[image]

```
@app.route("/notification", methods = ['POST', 'PUT'])
@token_required
def setNotifications(current_user, token):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = json.loads(request.data.decode('UTF-8'))
        subscription = form["subscription"]
        subscriptionId = form["subscriptionId"]
        dailyReminder = True if form['daily'] is True else False
        weeklyReminder = True if form['weekly'] is True else False
        yearlyReminder = True if form['yearly'] is True else False
        createNotif = db.session.query(User).filter(User.id == current_user.id).first()
        reminder = db.session.query(Reminder).filter(Reminder.subscriptionId  ==  subscriptionId).first()
        message = json.dumps({"token": token, "subscriptionId": subscriptionId})

 
        # print("Printing message" + message)
    
        VAPID_CLAIMS = {
            "sub": "my email"
        }
        if(createNotif.subscription == " "):
            createNotif.subscription = json.dumps(subscription)
            db.session.commit()

        
            try:
                # print("entering code")
                sched.add_job(lambda:modules.send_web_push(json.loads(createNotif.subscription), message, VAPID_PRIVATE_KEY, VAPID_CLAIMS), 'date', run_date = datetime.date(2021, 5,8))
                sched.start()
                # modules.send_web_push(json.loads(createNotif.subscription), message, VAPID_PRIVATE_KEY, VAPID_CLAIMS)
                # print("started here", flush= True)
                return jsonify({'success':1})
            except Exception as e:
                print("error",e)
                print("Could not send notification", flush=True)
                return jsonify({'failed':str(e)})
                

       
    

       
    if request.method == 'PUT':
        removeSubscription = db.session.query(User).filter(User.id == current_user.id).first()
        removeSubscription.subscription = " "
        db.session.commit()
        return jsonify({"success": "push notification has been updated"}), 200
```

Comment: Where is `sched` defined here, and why are you only starting it in a handler and not when your app starts?

Comment: You can try simple_scheduler https://pypi.org/project/simple-scheduler/ instead ...